# slash should be in roman font

Tags: fonts, listings

My tags are as follows:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}%

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,breakable}

\makeatletter
\lstdefinestyle{mypyscriptstyle}{%
upquote=true,
language=Python,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\fontsize{10}{14}\selectfont,
commentstyle=\tt\fontsize{10}{14}\selectfont, %
stringstyle=\ttfamily\slshape\fontsize{10}{14}\selectfont,%
showspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
showstringspaces=false,
columns=fixed,%%
breaklines=true,xleftmargin=4\p@,xrightmargin=0\p@,aboveskip=0\p@,belowskip=0\p@,
postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\rcurvearrowse\space}},
morecomment=[s]{"""}{"""},
morecomment=[s]{'''}{'''},
morecomment=[l]{\#},
keywordstyle=\bfseries,
keywords={},
sensitive=true,
string=[b]',
morestring=[b]",
escapechar={§},
alsoletter={_, .},
emphstyle=\color{black}\bfseries,
emph={assert, break, class, continue, def, del, elif, else, except, finally, for, global, help, in, lambda, not, or, pass, raise, return, try, while, with, yield, exec, Ellipsis, None, NotImplemented, ArithmeticError, AssertionError, AttributeError, EnvironmentError, EOFError, Exception, FloatingPointError, ImportError, IndentationError, IndexError, IOError, KeyboardInterrupt, KeyError, LookupError, MemoryError, NameError, NotImplementedError, OSError, OverflowError, ReferenceError, RuntimeError, StandardError, StopIteration, SyntaxError, SystemError, SystemExit, TabError, TypeError, UnboundLocalError, UnicodeDecodeError, UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeError, UnicodeTranslateError, ValueError, WindowsError, ZeroDivisionError, Warning, UserWarning, DeprecationWarning, PendingDeprecationWarning, SyntaxWarning, OverflowWarning, RuntimeWarning, FutureWarning, abs,  any, bin, bool, callable, chr, classmethod, compile, complex, delattr, dict, dir, divmod, enumerate, eval, filter, float, format, frozenset, getattr, globals, hasattr, hash, hex, id, input, int, isinstance, issubclass, iter, len, list, locals, map, max, min, object, oct, open, ord, pow, property, range, repr, reversed, round, setattr, set, slice, sorted, staticmethod, str, sum, super, tuple, type, vars, zip, apply, basestring, buffer, cmp, coerce, execfile, file, intern, long, , reduce, reload, unichr, unicode, xrange, import, __import__, print, match, search, readline, rstrip, group, VERBOSE, finditer, findall,
join, upper, lower, replace, find, count, strip, split, append, copy, clear, index, pop, sort, reverse, get, items, keys, values, update, intersection, union, symmetric_difference, difference, issubset, issuperset, if, name, mode, encoding, write, writelines, close, as, seek, whos, deepcopy, start, end, dimension, shape, ndim, size, mean, std, sqrt, exp, array, zeros, ones, arange, reshape, random, loadtxt, re, who, from, imread, imshow, loc, iloc, drop, median, hist, email, esearch, efetch, parse, description, id, seq, alignments, read,  }
}
\newtcblisting{testcode}{before skip=12pt, after skip=14.5pt,top=7.5\p@,bottom=8\p@,boxsep=0\p@,breakable,colback=black!6,left=7pt,right=9.5pt,arc=0pt,leftrule=0pt,rightrule=0pt,toprule=0pt,bottomrule=0pt,arc=0pt,listing
options={style=mypyscriptstyle,xleftmargin=4pt},listing only }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{testcode}
f.§§write(s + "\n") # write string s and go to a new line
f.§§writelines(["A\n", "B\n", "C\n"]) # write multiple strings provided as a list
\end{testcode}%


\end{document}
```

It works well, but the I need to get the slash character in Roman font throughout, as marked in the screenshot:

[image]

is this possible to do? please suggest...

Comment: If you want a local font change, use the literate option. But what do you mean by roman font in this case? You set columns to be fixed and then want to destroy it?

Comment: also you mean backslash (`\ `) slash is `/`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, yes I meant backslash only...

Comment: @TeXnician Now the backslash character comes in italic font, but I need it it roman font...

Comment: It's basically not italic font, but italic shape and you want it `\upshape`. As I shaid, you can literate this (see the listings documentation).

Comment: currently all three characters in `A\n` come from the same (sloped typewriter) font, do you just want to change the backslash? or all three ?

Comment: this is of course as you have specified strings as sloped: `stringstyle=\ttfamily\slshape\fontsize{10}{14}\selectfont`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I too find out where the problem was, but I need the text to be in italic but the backslash symbol should be in roman...

Comment: a very odd request:-)  (why show the string literals in mixed fonts?)  however you have the § escapechar so i assume you can do `§\textup{\backslashchar}§` or some such.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Great, it works, thanks a lot...But it may take huge time to do all places manually. anyhow, thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `literate` option to do this automatically.

[image: literate]

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,breakable}

\lstdefinestyle{mypyscriptstyle}{
  upquote=true,
  language=Python,
  basicstyle=\fontsize{10}{14}\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\fontsize{10}{14}\normalfont\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\fontsize{10}{14}\normalfont\ttfamily\slshape,
  showspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=fixed,
  breaklines=true,
  xleftmargin=4pt,
  xrightmargin=0pt,
  aboveskip=0pt,
  belowskip=0pt,
  postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\rcurvearrowse\space}},
  morecomment=[s]{"""}{"""},
  morecomment=[s]{'''}{'''},
  morecomment=[l]{\#},
  keywordstyle=\bfseries,
  keywords={},
  sensitive=true,
  string=[b]',
  morestring=[b]",
  escapechar={§},
  alsoletter={_, .},
  emphstyle=\color{black}\bfseries,
  literate={\\}{{\upshape\textbackslash}}1,
  emph={assert, break, class, continue, def, del, elif, else, except, finally, for, global, help, in, lambda, not, or, pass, raise, return, try, while, with, yield, exec, Ellipsis, None, NotImplemented, ArithmeticError, AssertionError, AttributeError, EnvironmentError, EOFError, Exception, FloatingPointError, ImportError, IndentationError, IndexError, IOError, KeyboardInterrupt, KeyError, LookupError, MemoryError, NameError, NotImplementedError, OSError, OverflowError, ReferenceError, RuntimeError, StandardError, StopIteration, SyntaxError, SystemError, SystemExit, TabError, TypeError, UnboundLocalError, UnicodeDecodeError, UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeError, UnicodeTranslateError, ValueError, WindowsError, ZeroDivisionError, Warning, UserWarning, DeprecationWarning, PendingDeprecationWarning, SyntaxWarning, OverflowWarning, RuntimeWarning, FutureWarning, abs,  any, bin, bool, callable, chr, classmethod, compile, complex, delattr, dict, dir, divmod, enumerate, eval, filter, float, format, frozenset, getattr, globals, hasattr, hash, hex, id, input, int, isinstance, issubclass, iter, len, list, locals, map, max, min, object, oct, open, ord, pow, property, range, repr, reversed, round, setattr, set, slice, sorted, staticmethod, str, sum, super, tuple, type, vars, zip, apply, basestring, buffer, cmp, coerce, execfile, file, intern, long, , reduce, reload, unichr, unicode, xrange, import, __import__, print, match, search, readline, rstrip, group, VERBOSE, finditer, findall,
join, upper, lower, replace, find, count, strip, split, append, copy, clear, index, pop, sort, reverse, get, items, keys, values, update, intersection, union, symmetric_difference, difference, issubset, issuperset, if, name, mode, encoding, write, writelines, close, as, seek, whos, deepcopy, start, end, dimension, shape, ndim, size, mean, std, sqrt, exp, array, zeros, ones, arange, reshape, random, loadtxt, re, who, from, imread, imshow, loc, iloc, drop, median, hist, email, esearch, efetch, parse, description, id, seq, alignments, read,  }
}

\newtcblisting{testcode}{
  before skip=12pt,
  after skip=14.5pt,
  top=7.5pt,
  bottom=8pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  breakable,
  colback=black!6,
  left=7pt,
  right=9.5pt,
  arc=0pt,
  leftrule=0pt,
  rightrule=0pt,
  toprule=0pt,
  bottomrule=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  listing options={style=mypyscriptstyle,xleftmargin=4pt},listing only
}


\begin{document}

\begin{testcode}
f.§§write(s + "\n") # write string s and go to a new line
f.§§writelines(["A\n", "B\n", "C\n"]) # write multiple strings provided as a list
\end{testcode}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I changed every `\p@` into `pt`, which is clearer and doesn't need `\makeatletter`. I also fixed the order of font declarations to avoid the deprecated `\tt`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I should start to check code I copy :)